# What is wrong in the below query?

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql

I have written this query on **oracle** database.

```
Select salary from emp having salary < (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMP ));
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47961/13

But it is not working .

Where am i wrong?

Comment: )); should be ); I believe.

Comment: `having` is used in combination with `GROUP BY` to narrow down results

Comment: you can apply having clause where you used group by , here there is no group by than just use where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select salary from emp where salary < (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMP ));
```

you can apply `having` clause where you used group by , here there is no group by than just use `where`

[**The HAVING Clause**](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php)

The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.

Answer (score 3):

things to do,

- use `WHERE` (*use having when comparing with aggregated condition*)
- remove extra parenthesis,

eg.

```
Select salary 
FROM emp 
WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMP );
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47961/15)

Answer (score 3):

Two errors:

- Use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`.
- Remove the extra parenthesis.

Try this:

```
SELECT salary
FROM emp
WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM emp);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47961/17

Answer (score 0):

```
Select salary from emp WHERE SALARY < (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMP );
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way using Having in Oracle:

```
SELECT sal FROM scott.emp
 GROUP BY sal
HAVING sal < (SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM scott.EMP)

/
SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) total_emps_by_dept
  FROM scott.emp
GROUP BY deptno
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
/
```